# Django many-to-many stores reverse relation as separate entry

Tags: python, django, manytomanyfield

I have a model called `Cell` that has a many-to-many relation with itself, called `combined_from`.

```
class Cell(models.Model):
    combined_from = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name='combined_into', blank=True)
    ...
```

What I'm trying to model is that a cell can be combined from multiple other cells, and that cells know they're combined into another cell (this is an end of life situation for these cells).

So, when I combine 3 cells (let's call them `c1, c2, c3`), I create a new one (called `c4`) and I do `c4.combined_from.add(c1, c2, c3)`.

So far so good, but the problem I have is that when I look at `c1.combined_from.all()`, I can see c4 appearing there!

I verified this behaviour with a minimal example in my terminal

```
>>> from cells.models.models import *
>>> from MCH4.utils.debug.queryrecorder import record_queries
>>> c1 = Cell.objects.first()
>>> c2 = Cell.objects.last()
>>> c1.combined_from.clear()
>>> c2.combined_from.clear()
>>> c1.combined_from.count()
0
>>> c2.combined_from.count()
0
>>> c1.combined_from.add(c2)
>>> c1.combined_from.count()
1
>>> c2.combined_from.count()
1
```

Any idea of how thus might happen or even how I can avoid this from happening again. I'm using django 1.11 if this is relevant information.